# Rows to column in SQL Server with duplicate name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables `ProductMaster` and `ProductParameter` and `ParameterMaster`.

`ProductMaster` contains multiple products and each product has multiple parameters whose values are stored in `productparameter`.

Now I need `ProductParameter` values as a column. I am using pivot but I can only get one product value. I want a list of all product like

```
ProductID   Name         ParameterValue1  ParameterValue2
--------------------------------------------------------------
  1         Product-1    test             test2
  2         Product-     anothervalue     another value2
```

Tables are as below

Parameter Master

```
ParameterID 
Name
```

ProductParameter

```
ProductParameterID
ProductID
ParameterID
Value
```

ProductMaster

```
ProductID
Name
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected output to help you better

Answer (score 0):

```
  select pp.ProductParameterId, pp.ProductID, pp.ParameterID, pp.value 
  from ParameterMaster pm, ProductParameter pp, ProductMaster p 
  where  p.name = pm.name 
  and 
  pp.ProductId = p.ProductId 
  and 
  pm.ParameterId = pp.ParameterId;
```

In oracle something like this:

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged